# How do I set radiobuttonlist selected value in jquery

Tags: jquery

Server side asp.net radiobuttonlist.  The value for the radiobuttonlist are ints with values 0, 1.  The text values are file, url.

So 0=File, 1=URL.

How in jquery can I set this radiobuttonlist value to 0?  I tried:

`$('#<%=rbAttachmentType.ClientID %>').find("input[value='0']").attr("checked", "checked");`

But this did not seem to work.

Comment: try `.prop("checked", true);` instead of attr()... also make sure your selector is fine.... check the value of `$('#<%=rbAttachmentType.ClientID %>').find("input[value='0']").length`

Comment: It should work, check if `$('#<%=rbAttachmentType.ClientID %>')` points to the correct parent and if the radiobutton has `value="0"`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - prop seemed to work...post it and I will accept the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) [instead of](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc) [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the checked state

```
$('#<%=rbAttachmentType.ClientID %>').find("input[value='0']").prop("checked", true);
```